Bonds in a zero interest rate environment
I've been looking at Pension Fund asset allocations.  Why would they have any allocation to bonds in an zero interest rate environment?
To make the point, let's assume the interest paid on these bonds was zero.  So why would any investor buy these bonds?  The investor will collect no interest, and bear all the downside risk if interest rates go up.  Aren't they just giving their money to someone and just hoping to get their money back.  Sure, the unthinkable happened and interest rates did go negative and so there was some modest appreciation on these bonds but the asymmetric return and risk profile seems to make a terrible investment in a zero interest rate environment.
I can understand how some retail investors might buy these bonds as a place to park money for security reasons but for Pension Funds, as entities that require returns to meet their obligations, any allocation to such bonds seem like a terrible investment.  It seems worse if they were making some type of risk parity allocation by over allocating to a low volatility asset, when the risk was only to the downside.  What am I missing?  Why were Pension Funds allocated to bonds in a zero interest rate environment?

In addition to @dm63's answers, it's worth noting that there won't necessarily be a free, zero-risk alternative. Bank accounts are only insured up to a certain balance (depends on where the bank is but its usually not more than a few hundred thousand USD, which is peanuts for these big funds.) They could hold physical cash, but that would have costs to store, insure, guard, etc.

Ok.  But why buy duration?  The PFs weren't the only ones that did this.  The banks (ag SVB) did it as well and then they got in trouble.  Seems like the ZIRP and other Fed actions are adding risk and volatility to the markets.

Could be a case of liability matching (another way of phrasing @dm63's reason B). https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/liabilitymatching.asp
Rates could go lower driving the liability higher.
It's also worth noting that some pensions have pretty inflexible mandates -- they may required by the board to have x% in equities, y% in bonds, etc., or may be required to match the duration of their liability. You could argue that in the negative rates environment they should change their mandates, but these can't necessarily be changed fast enough

Couple of possibilities
A) at the time, many believed that rates would indeed stay low for a long time and/or would actually go negative.  Seems ridiculous now but that is with hindsight.
B) many pension funds calculate the present value of their future obligations by discounting at bond yields.  Thus, investing in bonds minimizes their risk.  A departure from that approach would increase risk theoretically.

wrt to A--long term outlook would be reflected in cap, mkt assumptions and it would seem mean variance optimization would not allocate to return free risk; wrt to B) that would mean liab are at their highest, and therefore the funded status lowest; and other market assets would have appeared to be cheapest and therefore should have bought more equities right?

wrt to B. If you accept that you are a fiduciary acting on behalf of the pensioners only to deliver funds to them as reliably as possible, then B makes sense. It would not be right to take extra risks to make up for insufficient contributions by the employer, that is the employer's problem. Or so say the people who advocate approach B.
